# how to call javascript confirm dialog function in html.actionlink in asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to show a confirm dialog menu, when user clicks **DELETE** button.

But button doesn't trigger my script. After triggering JavaScript, if user chose OK, script must go to the action. Else, if user clicks the CANCEL, nothing should happen.

Here is the JavaScript code;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".confirmDialog").on("click", function (e) {
            // e.preventDefault(); use this or return false
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                height: 170,
                width: 350,
                show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
                modal: true,
                draggable: true,
                buttons: {
                    "OK": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        window.location = url;
                    }, "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is MVC codes;

```
<div style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold; font-size: larger; color: red;">
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Your-Action", new { @class = "confirmDialog" })</td>
    </tr>
</div>
<div id="dialog-confirm" style="display: none">
    <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>
        Are you sure ?
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Make sure, your link html looks like you expected

Answer (score 3):

The **Overload of Actionlink which you are using expects 3rd parameter as objectroutes not htmlattributes**.

Correct **actionlink** as shown:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Your-Action", new{} ,new { @class = "confirmDialog" })
```

OR

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Your-Action", null ,new { @class = "confirmDialog" })
```

The rest of your code is just fine..!!

Comment: @hislam...welcome.. if answer solved your problem then accept the answer so that accepted answer help others also..... thanks.